# The boundary between infinite clusters connected by closed and open bonds

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, percolation

In the following, I'll heuristically describe a boundary between two infinite clusters arising in percolation on the triangular lattice. I expect this concept has been well-studied before. My hope is to learn its name and potentially to learn about a few references describing it. As an aside, while I formulate everything below in terms of closed and open bonds, I suspect a more natural framing of the problem is in terms of *colored* bonds. My knowledge of bond percolation is largely elementary and informed solely by Grimmett's *Probability on Graphs*, so I hope the concept below is not too trivial.

---

Throughout this question, I'm imagining percolation on a lattice of points where a bond is open with probability $p$ and closed with probability $1-p$. A typical quantity considered is $\theta_{\text o}(p)$, the probability that the origin is part of an infinite cluster of vertices connected by open bonds.  The critical probability $p^*$ is defined via $\theta_{\text o}(p)>0$ for $p>p^*$ and $\theta_{\text o}(p)=0$ for $p<p^*$.

Here, I'll also consider $\theta_{\text c}(p)$, the probability that the origin is part of an infinite cluster connected by **closed** bonds. Note that we have that $\theta_{\text c}(p)>0$ for $p<1-p^*$ and $\theta_{\text c}(p)=0$ for $p>1-p^*$.

Depending on the lattice, it may be possible to have intervals of $p$ for which **both** of these probabilities $\theta_{\text o}$ and $\theta_{\text c}$ are nonzero. This occurs for those lattices with $p^*<1/2$. For example, the triangular lattice has $p^* = 2 \sin(\pi/18) \approx .35$, so there's a regime of $p$ between $.35$ and $.65$ for which $\theta_{\text o}$ and $\theta_{\text c}$ are greater than zero. I'll call this range of $p$ the "coexistence regime".

As discussed in Grimmett, when $\theta_{\text o}>0$, there is exactly one infinite cluster connected by open bonds. Similarly, when $\theta_{\text c}>0$, there is exactly one infinite cluster connected by closed bonds. That is, in the coexistence regime, we have one infinite cluster of vertices connected by open bonds and one infinite cluster of vertices connected by closed bonds.

The sets of vertices in the infinite open cluster and the infinite closed cluster can have some nonzero overlap, since a vertex has several bonds connected to it, some of which may be closed and connected to the infinite closed cluster and some of which may be open and connected to the infinite open cluster.

Does this set of boundary vertices straddling the single infinite open cluster and the single infinite closed cluster in the coexistence regime have a name? My hope is that it can be described by some stochastic curve in some appropriate scaling limit.